# Android Studio build error: too many entries

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build

I'm trying to run my Android Studio app on an emulator, but the build fails giving the error "Too many entries (82961)". The number contained in parenthesis changes. That's all the information I am given. This seems undocumented.

The number inside of the parenthesis in the error changes.

Update:
I checked if this was a rewording of "too many field references". In which the number of methods exceeds 65,536. I tried removing unused dependencies and multi-dexing. This did not solve the error.

Update:
I removed a large file system from the app that totaled about 91,196 files (this is close to the "Too many entries(91,740)"). I believe that the number is a count of the files in the project. removing a large file system contained in the project removes the issue.

I'm hoping that there is an alternative solution besides decreasing that file tree's size.

Update: All evidence suggests that the too meany entries appears when the file tree grew too large. There's is a cap on the number of files that can be contained in a project.

Comment: This was also asked on googles documentation bug tracker.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cap to how many files can be contained in a project

Answer (score 0):

I had it too with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.x`.
I fixed it by downgrading to `3.6.x` or upgrading to `4.1.x`.
I think it's because old versions of Zipflinger don't support zip64.

Comment: I did not use zipflinger and the latest update unfortunately did not solve the issue. Thanks for the post though.